# New photos app, upload from library?

Tags: macos, mac, icloud, photos, photos.app

I got the new Photos app + iCloud photos library going. It's great

But if I want to send an email from, say Gmail, and include a photo from my computer..

I can't choose from my photo library

The photos folder simply cannot be chosen when browsing local folders

So I have to first drag the photos to the desktop, for example, and THEN choose these files from gmail, and delete them afterwards

Is there not any other easy way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What mail app are you using? With Apple Mail, you just drag the photo from Photos to the email, or use the Share button at the top of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Solved

When browsing which picture to add to a mail (Gmail in browser, for example), there is a "photos" button down to the left

Clicking that, will show all the photos